# How to adjust columnWidth before blocks are rearranged

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I want columns to be a minimum width so I use the code below to determine what size each column should be on setup:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('#items');
    var numCols = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/290);
    var newWidth = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/numCols) - 5;
    var styleWidth = newWidth - 20;
    for (i=0; i<nummonos; i++) {
        divname = "brick" + i;
        document.getElementById(divname).style.width = styleWidth + 'px';
    }
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            columnWidth : newWidth,
            isAnimated: true
        });
    });
});
```

This works just fine for initialization but I now want to be able to adjust the column widths in the same way when the browser width changes (user rotates screen, etc.).

Is there an event I can intercept?

I am using version v2.1.08 of jQuery-masonry but I guess I could upgrade easily enough if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick thought but wouldn't it work if you created this as a function and call it on document.ready and on window.resize?

```
$(function(){ setColumns(); });

$(window).resize(function(){ setColumns(); });

// for IPad - orientation change doesn't always trigger window.resize functions
window.onorientationchange = function(){ setColumns(); });

function setColumns(){
    var $container = $('#items');
    var numCols = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/290);
    var newWidth = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/numCols) - 5;
    var styleWidth = newWidth - 20;
    for (i=0; i<nummonos; i++) {
        $('#brick' + i).css('width', styleWidth + 'px');
    }
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            columnWidth : newWidth,
            isAnimated: true
        });
    });
}
```

I used your existing code but I changed your for loop to use jQuery rather than the standard javascript getElementByID method because it's a personal pet peeve to see that typed out in the middle of a block of jquery. I'm not sure where you are getting the 'nummonos' counter variable but I assume you are setting it somewhere outside the code you posted.

Comment: I just went AFK for a while and worked out for myself that this was the right answer.  And of course it works just fine.  Sorry for the dumb question (and the untidy JavaScript).  The variable nummonos is set as a global variable server side from my database depending on how many bricks there are on the page.